# Graph-like info-graphics

Tags: graphs-and-networks

The Sunday, January 27, 2019 *New York Times* has a [superb info-graphic](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/01/26/opinion/sunday/paths-to-congress.html) describing the path from citizen to Member of the House of Representatives for the current members, including steps such as *college*, *ivy-league college*, *law school*, *business*, and so on.

[image]

Each path (red for Republican, blue for Democrat) starts at the starting node and then passes through an appropriate sequence of circular regions ("milestone disks") associated with each of these milestones.

The simplest approximation would be to create a traditional multi-graph (`Graph`), but that would miss several key features of this info-graphic:

- Each path must remain continuous and visible through each circular "milestone disk"
- Each path stays separate from the others and none cross needlessly, particularly within each "milestone disk"

Of course this info-graphic structure can be used for many applications, but as an illustration consider the input data of the following form:

```
{{"Jay Smith", "Democrat", "College", "Law School", "Military", "Congress"}, 
 {"Mary Jones", "Republican", "Ivy-league college", "Graduate school", "Business", Congress"}}
```

Presumably the designer can place the centers of the "milestone disks" which would be automatically scaled in size (based on the number of paths through it) and the paths would conform appropriately.

Special credit would be to be able to mouseover or click-highlight a single path and have the representative's *name*, *college* and so on appear, and to force all blue paths to pass through the top of a milestone disk and red paths to pass through the bottom of a milestone disk (to enable better comparison between Democrats and Republicans.

Comment: Fundamentally this is made challenging by what Szabolcs' mentions here: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1060237 If multigraph styling were supported properly this'd be easy.

Answer (score 8):

### Version 2

Get some node data to work with...:

```
BlockRandom[
  people = RandomEntity["Person", 1000]; 
  names = DeleteMissing@EntityValue[people, "FullName"];
  numPeeps = Length@names;
  mainCategory = RandomWord[2];
  wordChoices = TakeList[RandomWord[25], RandomInteger[{2, 5}, 5]];
  nodes =
   Join[
    List /@ names,
    List /@ RandomChoice[mainCategory, numPeeps],
    Transpose[RandomChoice[#, numPeeps] & /@ wordChoices],
    ConstantArray["End", {Length@names, 1}] ,
    2
    ]
  ];
```

And here's an updated single function to generate the graphics:

```
regroupArrows[arrowGroups_, graphPaths_] :=
  Module[
   {
    shrinkingArrows = arrowGroups,
    paths = graphPaths,
    arrow,
    arrows,
    arrowGroup
    },
   arrows =
    Table[
     Table[
      arrowGroup = shrinkingArrows[pair[[1]], pair[[2]]];
      If[MissingQ[arrowGroup], 
       pair = Reverse[pair];
       arrowGroup = shrinkingArrows[pair[[1]], pair[[2]]]
       ];
      Which[
       MissingQ[arrowGroup],
       {arrowGroup, pair},
       Length@arrowGroup > 0,
       arrow = arrowGroup[[1]];
       shrinkingArrows[pair[[1]], pair[[2]] ] = Rest[arrowGroup];
       arrow,
       True,
       {$Failed, pair}
       ],
      {pair, path}
      ],
     {path, Values@paths}
     ];
   AssociationThread[
    Keys[paths],
    arrows
    ]
   ];
joinBezier[arrows_] :=
  With[
   {
    bezzz = Cases[arrows, _BezierCurve, \[Infinity]],
    setBacks = arrows[[{1, -1}, -1]]
    },
   If[Length[bezzz] == Length[arrows],
    ReplacePart[
     arrows[[-1]], 
     {
      1 ->
       BezierCurve[
        Join @@ bezzz[[All, 1]]
        ],
      If[AllTrue[setBacks, NumericQ],
       -1 -> 0(*setBacks*),
       Nothing
       ]
      }
     ],
    arrows
    ]
   ];
makeStreamGraph // Clear
makeStreamGraph[
   nodes : {_, _, _, __} ..,
   embedding : _String : "LayeredDigraphEmbedding",
   colorFunction : _Function : (If[EvenQ[#2[[1]]], Hue[.666, .6, .6], 
       Hue[0, 1, .8]] &),
   diskStyles : 
    Except[_?OptionQ | {__String}, _Directive | _List] : {GrayLevel[
      1, .5], EdgeForm[Black]},
   useDynamics : True | False : False,
   labeledNodes : {___String} : {},
   ops : OptionsPattern[]
   ] :=
  Module[
   {
    mainCategory,
    mainCategoryColors,
    namedNodes,
    baseGraphs,
    baseWeights,
    choiceWeights,
    coreGraph,
    choicePositions,
    coreGraphics,
    arrows,
    disks,
    gComplexPositions,
    arrowGroups,
    graphPaths,
    arrowGroupings,
    endNodes
    },
   mainCategory = DeleteDuplicates@nodes[[All, 2]];
   endNodes = DeleteDuplicates@nodes[[All, -1]];
   mainCategoryColors =
    AssociationThread[mainCategory,
     MapIndexed[colorFunction, mainCategory]
     ];
   namedNodes = Association@Map[#[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3 ;;]] &, nodes];
   baseGraphs =
    MapThread[DirectedEdge, {Most[#], Rest[#]}] & /@ namedNodes;
   baseGraphs =
    KeySortBy[baseGraphs, #[[2]] &];
   baseWeights =
    Counts /@
     Transpose[Values[namedNodes]];
   If[Length@endNodes == 1, 
    baseWeights[[-1]] =
     AssociationThread[
      Keys[baseWeights[[-1]]], 
      {Mean@Flatten@Values@baseWeights}/2
      ]
    ];
   choiceWeights =
    Join @@ (N@baseWeights/Max[baseWeights]);
   choiceWeights =
    Thread[
     Keys[choiceWeights] ->
      Rescale[Rescale[Values@choiceWeights], {0, 1}, {.2, 1}]
     ];
   coreGraph =
    Graph[
     Flatten@Values[baseGraphs],
     GraphLayout -> embedding,
     VertexSize -> choiceWeights,
     VertexStyle -> White
     ];
   choicePositions =
    AssociationThread[
     VertexList[coreGraph],
     GraphEmbedding[coreGraph, embedding]
     ];
   coreGraphics = Show@coreGraph;
   If[Head@coreGraphics[[1]] =!= GraphicsComplex,
    Return[
     Failure["NotImplemented", <|
       "MessageTemplate" -> 
        "Not gonna work for this embedding for whatever reason"
       |>], Module]
    ];
   arrows = 
    Cases[coreGraphics, 
     a_Arrow :> (Cases[a, _Integer, \[Infinity]][[{1, -1}]] -> 
        a), \[Infinity]]; 
   disks = Cases[coreGraphics, _Disk, \[Infinity]];
   gComplexPositions =
    KeySelect[! MissingQ[#] &]@
       AssociationThread[# -> Range[Length[#]]] &@
     Lookup[
      AssociationMap[Reverse, choicePositions],
      Key /@ coreGraphics[[1, 1]]
      ];
   arrowGroups =
    GroupBy[arrows, #[[1, 1]] & -> (#[[1, 2]] -> #[[2]] &), 
     GroupBy[First -> Last]];
   graphPaths =
    Lookup[gComplexPositions, List @@ #] & /@ # & /@ baseGraphs;
   arrowGroupings = regroupArrows[arrowGroups, graphPaths];
   DynamicModule[
    {
     colors = mainCategoryColors,
     blends = Blend[{#, White}] & /@ mainCategoryColors
     },
    Graphics[
     GraphicsComplex[
      coreGraphics[[1, 1]],
      {
       {
        Arrowheads[0.],
        KeyValueMap[
         Which[useDynamics,
          {
            Tooltip[
             Dynamic[
              {
               If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"],
                Sequence @@
                 {
                  colors[#[[2]]],
                  AbsoluteThickness[8]
                  },
                Sequence @@ {
                  blends[#[[2]]],
                  AbsoluteThickness[1]
                  }
                ],
               #2
               }
              ],
              #[[1]]
             ]
            } &,
          Length@labeledNodes > 0,
          Tooltip[
            {

             Sequence @@

              If[MemberQ[labeledNodes, #[[1]]],
               {colors[#[[2]]], AbsoluteThickness[8]},
               {blends[#[[2]]], AbsoluteThickness[1]}
               ], 
             #2
             }, 
            #[[1]]
            ] &,
          True,
          Tooltip[
            {
             colors[#[[2]]], AbsoluteThickness[1], #2
             }, 
            #[[1]]
            ] &
          ],
         (*joinBezier/@*)
         KeySortBy[
          arrowGroupings,
          { MemberQ[labeledNodes, #[[1]]] &}
          ]
         ]
        },
       {
        Sequence @@ Flatten@{diskStyles},
        MapThread[Tooltip, { disks, VertexList[coreGraph]}]
        }
       }
      ],
     ops
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

Now we can use it like normal:

```
makeStreamGraph[nodes, ImageSize -> {200, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Or try a different embedding:

```
makeStreamGraph[nodes, "SpringEmbedding", 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}]
```

[image]

Label some specific nodes:

```
makeStreamGraph[nodes, "SpringEmbedding", nodes[[;; 5, 1]], 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}]
```

[image]

Or have a `Dynamic` implementation where we can mouse over a path and see it (note that this is preliminary and slow):

```
makeStreamGraph[nodes, "SpringEmbedding", True, 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}]
```

[image]

### Version 1

#### Implementation

Here's a place to start, although I don't have time to do the final annoying bits to get it to actually work.

We'll start with some core data of the form you provided:

```
BlockRandom[
  people = RandomEntity["Person", 1000]; 
  names = DeleteMissing@EntityValue[people, "FullName"];
  numPeeps = Length@names;
  mainCategory = RandomWord[2];
  wordChoices = Partition[RandomWord[15], 5];
  nodes =
   Join[
    List /@ names,
    List /@ RandomChoice[mainCategory, numPeeps],
    Transpose[RandomChoice[#, numPeeps] & /@ wordChoices],
    2
    ]
  ];
```

Then we'll extract each subgraph we want to build off of these:

```
namedNodes =
  Association@
   Map[#[[1 ;; 2]] -> #[[3 ;;]] &, nodes];
baseGraphs =
  MapThread[UndirectedEdge, {Most[#], Rest[#]}] & /@ namedNodes;
```

Then we sort this so everything looks nice in the end:

```
baseGraphs = KeySortBy[baseGraphs, #[[2]] &];
```

Next we assign weights for each node:

```
choiceWeights =
  Join @@
    With[
     {
      base =
       Counts /@
        Transpose[nodes[[All, 3 ;;]]]
      },
     N@base/Max[base]
     ] // Thread[Keys[#] ->
      Rescale[Rescale[Values@#], {0, 1}, {.2, 1}]
     ] &;
```

And we extract the vertex coordinates of the best looking multigraph I could find:

```
coreGraph =
  Graph[
   Flatten@Values[baseGraphs]
   ];
choicePositions =
  AssociationThread[
   VertexList[coreGraph],
   GraphEmbedding[coreGraph, "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]
   ];
```

Now here comes the hard part. We can't disambiguate each multigraph edge, so we really need to build this code ourselves. First we extract all the arrows and group them by their coordinates:

```
coreGraphics = Show@coreGraph;
postProcessArrow[a_Arrow] := 
  Cases[a, _Integer, \[Infinity]][[{1, -1}]] -> a;
arrows = Cases[coreGraphics, 
   a_Arrow :> postProcessArrow[a], \[Infinity]];
disks = Cases[coreGraphics, _Disk, \[Infinity]];
```

Then we try to rebuild our arrow paths:

```
arrowGroups =
  GroupBy[arrows, #[[1, 1]] & -> (#[[1, 2]] -> #[[2]] &), 
   GroupBy[First -> Last]];

graphPaths =
  Lookup[gComplexPositions, List @@ #] & /@ # & /@ baseGraphs;

arrowGroupings =
  Module[
   {
    shrinkingArrows = arrowGroups,
    paths = graphPaths,
    arrow,
    arrows,
    arrowGroup
    },
   arrows =
    Table[
     Table[
      arrowGroup = shrinkingArrows[pair[[1]], pair[[2]]];
      If[MissingQ[arrowGroup], 
       pair = Reverse[pair];
       arrowGroup = shrinkingArrows[pair[[1]], pair[[2]]]
       ];
      Which[
       MissingQ[arrowGroup],
       {arrowGroup, pair},
       Length@arrowGroup > 0,
       arrow = arrowGroup[[1]];
       shrinkingArrows[pair[[1]], pair[[2]] ] = Rest[arrowGroup];
       arrow,
       True,
       {$Failed, pair}
       ],
      {pair, path}
      ],
     {path, Values@paths}
     ];
   AssociationThread[
    Keys[paths],
    arrows
    ]
   ];
```

And finally remake our info graphic:

```
GraphicsComplex[
  coreGraphics[[1, 1]],
  {
   Arrowheads[0.],
   KeyValueMap[
    {If[#[[2]] === mainCategory[[2]], Hue[0, 1, .8], 
       Hue[.666, .6, .6]], Tooltip[#2, #[[1]]]} &,
    arrowGroupings
    ],
   {
    White, EdgeForm[Black],
    MapThread[Tooltip, { disks, VertexList[coreGraph]}]
    }
   }
  ] // Graphics[#, ImageSize -> 1000] &
```

[image]

Now I haven't made sure all the paths are clean, but for non-random data we might get that more-or-less for free. Oh yeah and I have tooltips on there.

One nice thing about this approach is we can really get everything directly from `coreGraph` so we don't need to rebuild all the `Graphics` architecture ourselves.

Comment: Wow... thanks for all the work... great start (+1).  But as you recognize, the hard part is what is yet to be done.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thinking about it more you could pre-sort the `arrowGroups` so that the higher "radius" stuff is always at the bottom of the list. If you also presort your `baseGraphs` by `mainCategory` we should actually be doing just fine.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork how does it look now? All it took was a bit of sorting :)

Comment: Superb work... thanks so very much.  Nevertheless, the requirement that the lines be visible *within* each disk.  There are a few other desiderata.  Let me give the rest of answerers a chance to address these....  Again:  great work!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ah I see. There's a potential approach I can think of that involves taking the individual `BezierCurves` and splicing them together, but I'll deal with that later if you're still interested.

Comment: Oh I'm very much interested.  To get an interactive figure like this in *Mathematica* would be a great benefit to many people:  https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2019/01/26/opinion/sunday/paths-to-congress.html

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Should be doable. I probably won't have time for it for a few days though. It won't take dramatically more than what I have to make the line coloring `Dynamic`, though.

Comment: I'll hold off accepting for three days and eagerly await your next posting.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork in the name of procrastination I added a few of these features. I need to add more, but we're getting closer.

Comment: Oh this is getting *good*!  Keep up the effort... we all appreciate it.